# retrieving an element/text after it's been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5X5 text box with letters that randomly change every few seconds. I figured out how to make the box selectable. Now I want to be able to retrieve the letter that's appearing within the box at the time that I click. I'm new to coding, but after researching, I thought I could combine the .click function with the .text() function. I add a

tag and tried to print the clicked letter within it. It's not working. I'm I using the .text() function incorrectly? I haven't used it before so I'm not sure.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>LetterTouch</title>
</head>

  <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gameboard.css">
  <!-- <link href="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#squares").selectable();

      });

      var nIntervId;

var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

function changeLetters() {
    nIntervId = setInterval(boardGen, 1500);
}

function boardGen() {
    $('li').each(function (i, e) {
        $(e).text(letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)));
    })
}




$( "li" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).text();
    $( "p" ).html(  );
        });

changeLetters();

 </script>

<body>



<ol id="squares">
  <li class="A1"></li>
  <li class="A2"></li>
  <li class="A3"></li>
  <li class="A4"></li>
  <li class="A5"></li>
  <li class="B1"></li>
  <li class="B2"></li>
  <li class="B3"></li>
  <li class="B4"></li>
  <li class="B5"></li>
  <li class="C1"></li>
  <li class="C2"></li>
  <li class="C3"></li>
  <li class="C4"></li>
  <li class="C5"></li>
  <li class="D1"></li>
  <li class="D2"></li>
  <li class="D3"></li>
  <li class="D4"></li>
  <li class="D5"></li>

  <p> H </p> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$(this).text()`.

Comment: what error u getting? any console error ?

Comment: Your explanations all make a lot of sense. I've tried each of them with no result. I'll keep researching and trying and will let you guys know if I find success. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be this is what you are trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/X24s9/

```
$("document").ready(function() {

  $("#squares").selectable();


  $( "#squares" ).on('click', 'li', function() {
    var txt = $( this ).text();
    $("p").html(txt);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the text of that clicked li element as the parameter of html() function gonna be run on behalf of the p tag.

Try,

```
$("#squares li").click(function() {
    $("p").html($(this).text());
});
```

And also your html seems invalid, please try to close that `<ol>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the .text() property.

```
 $("p").html($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're inserting the characters inside the li, you will want to use .text() to pick them up.

e.g.

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {
    $( "p" ).html($(this).text());
});
```

what this does is that I took the html content of the li - referenced by $(this).text(), and assigned that to be the content of the p element. How .html() works is that placing a string parameter in it assigns that to its html content.